# Session data could not be read from another window

Tags: javascript, php, html

On a test1.php I have this:

```
<?php
    echo "Session variables are about to be set.";
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["animal"] = "cat";
    echo "Session variables are set.";
    echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["animal"] . ".";
?>

<div ms_positioning="text2D" class="style7"><a href="javascript:winOpen();" test2.php="">Contact Information</a></div>

<script>
function winOpen() {

    window.open("/test2.php",null,"scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300,top=100,left=100");

}
</script>
```

In test2.php, I have this:

```
<?php
    // Echo session variables that were set on previous page
    echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["animal"] . ".";
?>
```

But data is not showing up on test2.php.  It did echo back on test1.php.

any suggestions?

Comment: did you start the session everywhere? No? Do. http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test1.php should be like this:

```
<?php
    session_start(); // In case you come back to test1.php
    echo "Session variables are about to be set.";
    // Set session variables
    $_SESSION["animal"] = "cat";
    echo "Session variables are set.";
    echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["animal"] . ".";
?>

<div ms_positioning="text2D" class="style7"><a href="javascript:winOpen();" test2.php="">Contact Information</a></div>

<script>
function winOpen() {

    window.open("/test2.php",null,"scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300,top=100,left=100");

}
</script>
```

And test2.php should like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // Echo session variables that were set on previous page
    echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["animal"] . ".";
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call

```
session_start();
```

function at the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 2):

Put in fisrt of code
`session_start();`

Try this

```
<?php 
session_start();
// Echo session variables that were set on previous page
echo "Favorite animal is " . $_SESSION["animal"] . ".";
?>
```